# RealmDB - React Native - Unable to open a realm at path '.management'

Tags: android, react-native, realm, genymotion

In a react-native project running Android on Genymotion I had the app running.  At one point I received an issue and uninstalled the app from the VM.  Upon re-running the app I received an alert:

```
Unable to open a realm at path '.management'.
Please use a path where your app has read-write permissions. <unknown>
    index.js:100 loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:171 guardedLoadModule
    require.js:123
_require
    require.js:107 <unknown>
    Repeaters.js:6 loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:171 guardedLoadModule
    require.js:123
_require
    require.js:107 <unknown>
    NavigationRouter.js:12 loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:171 guardedLoadModule
    require.js:123
_require
    require.js:107 <unknown>
    RootContainer.js:5 loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:171 guardedLoadModule
    require.js:123
_require
    require.js:107 <unknown>
    index.android.js:8 loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:171 guardedLoadModule
    require.js:116
_require
    require.js:107 global code
    require-0.js:1
```

I've tried shutting off Genymotion, uninstalling via adb shell, setting permissions manually via adb shell.  I can't seem to fix the problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the path that you are supplying to the `Realm` constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same problem because of the [migrations](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#linear-migrations). In ios worked fine but in android didn't.

Code before

```
let nextSchemaIndex = Realm.schemaVersion(Realm.defaultPath);
while (nextSchemaIndex < schemas.length) {
  const migratedRealm = new Realm(schemas[nextSchemaIndex]);
  nextSchemaIndex += 1;
  migratedRealm.close();
}
```

Code now

```
let nextSchemaIndex = Realm.schemaVersion(Realm.defaultPath);
while (nextSchemaIndex < schemas.length) {
  const migratedRealm = new Realm({ ...schemas[nextSchemaIndex] });
  nextSchemaIndex += 1;
  migratedRealm.close();
}
```

**Creating a new object for the Realm constructor solve the issue.**

Hopes it's helps.

I didn't set a path for the schema but maybe [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/526) helps also.